If $a,b,c \in R$ such that $a < b < c < d$ , show that $(x-a)(x-c) + 2(x-b)(x-d) = 0$ has real and distinct roots .

If $a,b,c \in R$  such that $a < b < c < d$ , show that $(x-a)(x-c) + 2(x-b)(x-d) = 0$ has real and distinct roots .

I'm not getting good manipulation idea to show discriminant positive , also wherever I searched i found only same not much intuitive solution . I m seeking for good intuitive solutions here thanks in advance.
Someone shared a neat idea of sign changes here but still I'm looking for some good manipulative ideas too .

The tag (theory-of-equations) was previously discussed on meta and the consensus was that the tag should be removed.
I'd say that if you still think that such tag should exist, you should probably start a discussion on meta about that tag - to see whether other users of the site consider such tag to be useful.

@MartinSleziak i didn't know about it sorry but I m fine with removal of this tag

If $f(x)=(x-a)(x-c) + 2(x-b)(x-d)$ then $f(a)>0$, $f(b)<0$ and $f(d)>0$, so there must be a root between $a$ and $b$ and a root between $b$ and $d$.

This is indeed the best observation and also a good reminder that manipulations aren't the only main thing in algebra but still I m seeking for some good manipulation trick for this question
